# how to prevent Default scroll in Android?

Tags: android

Need help,
      See the following screen, (This is my actual home screen)
[image]

But, when I run my Application It looks as follows (Screen When I run my application
[image]

Here I need to drag (Scroll) the screen to see the footer part. I wants to avoid this, Can anybody help me out in this Please. Thank You.!

Comment: @baloo I tried to add Layout XML in my above question, but some how StackOverflow is not accepting it. Really Sorry..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope this will help you. Use following

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical">


    <!-- header part -->
     <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/ll_header"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            ...
        </LinearLayout>

    <!-- scroll view part -->
        <ScrollView 
         android:id="@+id/sv_container"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_above="@+id/ll_fooetr">

        </ScrollView>

        <!-- footer part -->
        <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/ll_footer"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            ...
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` for your activity, and inside it use a `ScrollView` for the inside part (which should be scrolled).

So, perhaps something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <!-- all your scrollable stuff goes here -->
    </ScrollView>

    <!-- here's your footer -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[Documentation on ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

**Edit:**
I think `RelativeLayout` (as main Layout) will serve you the best, as it allows you to align itself against parent's edges.

[Documentation on RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)